# write osg texture to png missing plugin

Tags: textures, writetofile, openscenegraph

We are trying to write a `osg::Image` to a file using 
`osgDB::writeImageFile` but unfortunately we get an error:

```
Could not find plugin to write to file
```

We are using the osg binaries from http://www.alphapixel.com/osg/downloads/free-openscenegraph-binary-downloads under a Ubuntu 11.04 64bit. Our application is built as a 32bit application.

Do you know a way how to fix these plugin issues?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I found was:
1. Download lipng setup from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm and the zlib.lib as well and
2. Manually change the dependencies in the linker: "libpng.lib" and "zlib.lib"

Sorry, it is not the optimal solution. I hope it helps!